# Embed OneDrive powerpoint at iframe on site

Tags: javascript, iframe, powerpoint, onedrive

I'm trying to add a PowerPoint presentation to my website. I use URL
https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=XXXX&resid=XXXX&authkey=XXXX&wdAr=XXXX&wdslideindex=2
I want to know what other parameters can be set in the url, for example, as a slide number - wdslideindex
When I start a presentation, a start window with the powerpoint logo appears on the site, I want to remove it. There is also a bottom panel on the slides with buttons, I also want to remove it
For example, in order to remove the panel in google drive, you need to write in the url - rm=minimal.[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think that's possible, from my research. Doesnt seem to be much documentation on this.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/722870/embed-onedrive-powerpoint-at-iframe-on-site.html